# Can I define how accessing python object (and not just its attributes) is handled?

Tags: python

I have a custom class in python, that I would like to behave in a certain way **if the object itself (i.e., and not one if its methods/properties) is accessed**.

This is a contrived minimal working example to show what I mean. I have a class that holds various `pandas` `DataFrame`s so that they can separately be manipulated:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class SplitDataFrame:
    
    def __init__(self, df0, df1):
        self._dfs = [df0, df1]
        
    def increase(self, num, inc):
        self._dfs[num] = self._dfs[num] + inc
        
    @property
    def asonedf(self):
        return pd.concat(self._dfs, axis=1)


d = SplitDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2), columns=['a','b']),
                   pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2), columns=['q','r']))
d.increase(0, 10)
```

This works, and I can examine that `d._dfs` now indeed is

```
[           a          b
 0  10.845681  10.561956
 1  10.036739  10.262282,
           q         r
 0  0.164336  0.412171
 1  0.440800  0.945003]
```

So far, so good.

Now, I would like to change/add to the class's definition so that, when not using the `.increase` method, it returns the concatenated dataframe. In other words, when accessing `d`, I would like it to return the same dataframe as when typing `d.asonedf`, i.e.,

```
           a          b         q         r
0  10.143904  10.154455  0.776952  0.247526
1  10.039038  10.619113  0.443737  0.040389
```

That way, the object more closely follows the `pandas.DataFrame` api:

- instead of needing to use `d.asonedf['a']`, I could access `d['a']`;
- instead of needing to use `d.asonedf + 12`, I could do `d + 12`;
- etc.

Is that possible?

I could make `SplitDataFrame` inherit from `pandas.DataFrame`, but that does not magically add the desired behaviour.

Many thanks!

Comment: "That way, I could access `d['a']`" - you achieve that by defining `__getitem__`, the indexing operator, not by doing the thing you're asking for. What you're asking for has all kinds of conceptual problems and doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica for your comment. Yes, I could implement `__getitem__` for this, and I could implement `__add__` for the `+12` operation. But I don't think wrapping all `pandas.DataFrame` magic methods is the way to go here; I would like to create a `pandas.DataFrame` on the fly in which all that functionality is already implemented natively.                      Could you explain what you mean with "all kinds of conceptual problems"?

Comment: I could change the signature to `SplitDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame)`, if that's what you mean? But that does not magically add the desired behaviour.

Comment: What you're asking for makes it impossible to return your object from a function, or pass your object to a function, or assign your object to a variable, or do pretty much anything with it. It would even break your `increase` method, because `self` would automatically be replaced by a dataframe when `increase` tries to do `self._dfs`, and dataframes have no `_dfs` attribute. It would become nearly impossible to do anything at all with your object.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, ah, I'm starting to see what you mean... thanks! If I understand correctly, that means my only option is to inherit from `pandas.DataFrame`, and store the data passed to `__init__` as actual columns to `self`, right? And I'd have to build a work-around for `increase`, e.g. using the column names stored during instantiation.

Comment: I am confused how this question fundamentally differs from [the one asked half an hour earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670256/define-how-accessing-python-object-and-not-just-its-attributes-is-handled). Are they the same problem asked slightly differently?

Comment: This question is indeed not fundamentally different. An admin deemed the previous question a duplicate of another question, and he/she unhelpfully closed it. The feedback/suggestion was that I ask a new question, so that's what I did

Comment: The "ask a new question" means you can ask *an entirely new* question about something else. Just re-asking practically the same question is not meant by it!

Comment: Yes, I agree. But that's what was suggested and I didn't want to argue ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You could of course proxy all relevant magic methods to a concatenated dataframe on demand. If you don't want to repeat yourself endlessly, you could dynamically do that.

I'm not saying this is the way to go, but it kind of works:

```
import textwrap

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class SplitDataFrame:
    def __init__(self, df0, df1):
        self._dfs = [df0, df1]

    def increase(self, num, inc):
        self._dfs[num] = self._dfs[num] + inc

    for name in dir(pd.DataFrame):
        if name in (
            "__init__",
            "__new__",
            "__getattribute__",
            "__getattr__",
            "__setattr__",
        ) or not callable(getattr(pd.DataFrame, name)):
            continue
        exec(
            textwrap.dedent(
                f"""
                def {name}(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    return pd.concat(self._dfs, axis=1).{name}(*args, **kwargs)
                """
            )
        )
```

As you might guess, there's all kind of strings attached to this solution, and it uses horrible practices (using `exec`, using `dir`, ...).

At the very least I would implement `__repr__` so you don't lie to yourself about what kind of object this is, and maybe you'd want to explicitly enumerate all methods you want defined instead of getting them via `dir()`. Instead of `exec()` you can define the function normally and then set it on the class with `setattr`.

Comment: Why the `super`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Good point, leftover from experiments.